# Base Table or view not found SQLSTATE[42S02]

Tags: migration

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'vita_valorelondon.general_settings' doesn't exist (SQL: select `active_template` from `general_settings` limit 1)

Databse.php

```
  'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'vita_valorelondon'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=vita_valorelondon
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

How To Fix This ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in Database.php file or .env file. Issue is in where you call general settings model. or in general settings model.

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GeneralSetting extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $casts = ['mail_config' => 'object'];

    public function scopeSitename($query, $page_title)
    {
        $page_title = empty($page_title) ? '' : ' - ' . $page_title;
        return $this->sitename . $page_title;
    }
}

Comment: this is my general general setting model

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times this error comes when we didn't give grant to specific schema.

example :

I create table 'users' in schema 'user'

so when I want to use it in another schema like 'product' I have to give grant to this schema from 'user' schema.

oracle code :

```
grant select , insert , update , delete on users to product

users : is a table in a 'user' schema

product : is a new schema that want to use of table 'users'
```

Comment: Can you tell me what to do in laravel

Comment: I think you don't need to change your code in Laravel but you have to run a one line code in database like Sql, Oracle, Mysql ,...

Answer (score 0):

This command help me:-

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```